# AngularJS ui-select minimum-input-length not telling user to type in more characters

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select

Is there any already made extension or even built-in option for angularJS's ui-select (select2 theme) to display information for user to input more characters to display results when using

```
 minimum-input-length=3
```

option? I am talking about feature like

```
formatInputTooShort(function() {return "Input more characters!;});
```

in jQuery select2 (https://select2.github.io/select2/).

Here's plunker set up with basic select using library versions I use: http://plnkr.co/edit/K9alAMAzvUqCY7Or8RwY?p=preview

I've been googling this for ages and haven't been able to find any existing solution.

Sorry for that not very valid code snippets, I had to use them to be able to include plunker snippet. Any help or hint appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems in my UI. I used [angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices) and use that for all my dropdowns now (have a few). While this is not a native select2 choice, angular-ui dropdowns can be used to make dropdowns just like select2 using the attribute `theme="select2"`

To limit on input of at least 3 characters, here's what you do:

Controller JS:

```
$scope.limitTitleSearch = 5000; //this should be initialised to more than the number of entries the dropdown holds
$scope.checkTitle = function(lettersTyped){
        if(lettersTyped.length > 2){
            $scope.limitTitleSearch = 500;
        }else{
            $scope.limitTitleSearch = 0;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

Use  to display message for inputting more than 3 characters. Like:

```
<ui-select-no-choice>
    Type at least 3 chars for options to load
</ui-select-no-choice>
```

and use the `refresh` attribute of `ui-select-choices` to call that JS function.

so your HTML looks

```
<ui-select-choices 
  refresh="checkTitle($select.search)"
  refresh-delay="1000"
  repeat="item in (itemArray | filter: $select.search limitTo: limitTitleSearch) track by item.id">
    <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
//add <ui-select-no-choices code here
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: There is native parameter for limiting minimum user input length, it's called minimum-input-length and it eats number of characters. I was lacking option provided by ui-select-no-choice. While it's not exacly what I want to achieve, it will, in combination with minimum-input-length,  probably do for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

See the below link which is similar to your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41757481/4434112

but in your case, in ui-select plugin.js and edit the template "select2/select.tpl.html" (for theme select2) change the placeholder to your desired message

**placeholder="Input minimum 3 characters!"**

so in template it will be as shown here:

```
<input type=\"search\" ........... placeholder=\"Input minimum 3 characters!\">
```