# ui select angularjs set maxlength for input value (ui select match)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, ui-select2, angular-ui-select

I want an extra attribute just like "Placeholder" is passing from ui select match. I want to set maxlength of select input. I can set it through select.min.js adding attribute maxlength="" but i think making change to lib. file is not a solution.

[Just like i have adde maxlength="500" in input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3YIt.png)

please help me around.

Thanks

Comment: If i understood you correctly, this is what you want to achieve (check the dropdown out there) http://john-oc.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your collection using the angular's limitTo filter. Look at the [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) reference.

Comment: I dont want max length for the drop down. I want to implement maxlength for that search box which take that value to be search within from dropdown. Hope you got my question now ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are using ui-select with tagging (as combo-box).

in this to achieve your desired functionality:

go to ui-select plugin.js and edit the template "select2/select.tpl.html" (for theme select2):

**ng-attr-maxlength="{{$select.tagging.isActivated ? 50 : ''}}"**

add the above line to template as shown here:

```
<input type=\"search\" ........... ng-attr-maxlength=\"{{$select.tagging.isActivated ? 500 : ''}}\">
```

if you want to restrict input search itself then directly add maxlength attribute:

```
<input type=\"search\" ........... maxlength=\"500\">
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can change attribute through templateCache

```
.run(function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put("bootstrap/select-multiple.tpl.html","<div class=\"ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown form-control\" ng-class=\"{open: $select.open}\"><div><div class=\"ui-select-match\"></div><input maxlength='5' type=\"search\" autocomplete=\"off\" autocorrect=\"off\" autocapitalize=\"off\" spellcheck=\"false\" class=\"ui-select-search input-xs\" placeholder=\"{{$selectMultiple.getPlaceholder()}}\" ng-disabled=\"$select.disabled\" ng-click=\"$select.activate()\" ng-model=\"$select.search\" role=\"combobox\" aria-expanded=\"{{$select.open}}\" aria-label=\"{{$select.baseTitle}}\" ng-class=\"{\'spinner\': $select.refreshing}\" ondrop=\"return false;\"></div><div class=\"ui-select-choices\"></div><div class=\"ui-select-no-choice\"></div></div>");
    })
```

Original templates can be find on bottom of file select.js